# Java doesn't see a variable in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have created a check box called cboFlavour in the constructor of the class, and also created the method so I can assign some string values to it like this :

```
   JComboBox cboFlavour = new JComboBox();
    cboFlavour.setBounds(20, 46, 192, 22);
    contentPane.add(cboFlavour);

private void loadFlavour() {
        for(String flavours : flavour) {
            cboFlavour.addItem(flavours);
        }
    }
```

But Eclipse says that cboFlavour cannot be resolve (doesn't see that is created)?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"Eclipse doesn't see.."* Don't confuse your IDE with the compiler acting on the rules of the language. The IDE is just an editor. 3) `cboFlavour.setBounds(20, 46, 192, 22);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) ..

Comment: .. along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your variable from a different method you could do something along these lines.

```
private JComboBox cboFlavour;

public ClassName() {
    cboFlavour = new JComboBox();
    cboFlavour.setBounds(20, 46, 192, 22);
    contentPane.add(cboFlavour);
}
```

Comment: No. I think is because the field was not declared as private in the class, only in the constructor of the class and that's why the method loadFlavour() cannot see it. Thank you anyway :)